I want download an extension, but I can't find it under Administer > System Settings > Extensions
As the title says, I want to install this extension called Mosaico Message Templates.
Here is a link to the extension web page: https://civicrm.org/extensions/mosaico-message-templates
However, I can't seem to find the extension under Administer > System Settings > Extensions. I've looked under Extensions and Add New, but no luck.
Can anyone please help on what I can do to install the extension if i cant see it?
Thank you!

See https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/mosaicomsgtpl#installation. You need to download it manually.

Thank you so much! I got it working perfectly now!
